# Entity Framework Generate Database Schema (SQL) with Default Table Values

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-5, ef-model-first

I am using EF 5 and SQL Server 2005, Model First (sort of).

By sort of, I mean that I typically build my schema in the SQL Server designer, but import the schema into EF so I have a visual view. There is often round-tripping.

However, I noticed that when I try to generate the DB schema based on the EF model, it skips all of the NEWID() default values that I have assigned as default values to my Guid IDs, but it doesn't skip the identity fields of type int.

I found this post explaining the reasoning for this:
[Entity Framework 4 and Default Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586466/entity-framework-4-and-default-values)

However, it doesn't answer my question: How do I get Entity Framework to generate a SQL DDL database schema with default values of NEWID() for my uniqueidentifier types?

NOTE:

I don't care about how to set them from the POCO entities and so forth (there are plenty of posts describing that) - my concern is getting the SQL DDL generated right so I can seed the database without worrying about these values going missing.

Answer (score 2):

Using Entity Framework Migrations, you can use the [GUID column builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.builders.columnbuilder.guid.aspx) and its `DefaultValueSql` parameter. The value of that parameter can be the string `"NEWID()"`. This should take care of proper DDL generation.

Next you should declare these properties as database-generated using attributes or the fluent model builder, so that EF ignores the values set in your POCOs (which will be null for new objects).

Comment: Thanks. Entity framework migrations is for code first, so I am not sure if it will help anyone who comes across this question. I ended up switching to code first several months ago anyway and more recently to code first migrations. +1 for your effort, but will only accept an answer that is for model first as the correct one.

Comment: You're right, we switched so long ago I didn't even realize. Oh well ;).